# Routing to a page with sections in two slots

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a question regarding routing.

We have a detail page that consists of two different sections. 
However, these two components/sections are in different slots.

How does the routing work in such a case ? 
How can we access the detail page ?
Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Routing in Spartacus is not directly related to the *structure* of the CMS page. A url is connected to a page structure by using the following flow:

1. If it's a custom application route, spartacus will not touch it
2. if it's a product or category route, use configurable routing to match the product or category page from the cms
3. otherwise it's treated as a ContentPage, the CMS is queried for a matching `page.label` (or part of it).
4. if non of the above is found, the not-found content page is loaded.

The page structure which is loaded from the CMS is rendered on the page. The `LayoutComponent` is used to render the template, the `PageComponent` is used to render the page slots and the `ComponentWrapperDirective` is used to map the cms components to JS components.

If you have 2 different "sections", I assume you're talking about slots. In order to render the slots, you need to configure the Layout Configuration, see https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/page-layout/. Since the CMS doesn't provide any info on the order an location of slots, this additional configuration is required.

There's much more to it, but I hope this gives you a start at least.